# How does concave bowl amplifies the sound?

Tags: acoustics

I recently came across an article / answer in Quora [see here](http://qr.ae/NZu1D) that mentioned that if we place the iPhone in a bowl and play music, the volume is amplified.

What is the physics principle behind this?

Answer (score 3):

A hard surface like a metal, ceramic or glass bowl will probably reflect more sound than it absorbs or transmits. Therefore more of the phone's sound output is reflected towards the listener.

Some phones have loudspeakers at the rear (because the front is filled with glass screen) and so this effect is especially noticeable.

Some Apple iPhones have speakers in the bottom edge facing downwards, it is still probably advantageous to reflect this sound energy forward.

Without the bowl, much of the sound energy that is radiated away from  the listener will be absorbed before it is reflected and any reflected sound is likely to be reflected from a surface that is further away (and therefore the volume is diminished according to the inverse square law).

There's no real amplification of sound, only a redirection of otherwise wasted sound energy.